# Sweet town in Pennsylvania

Tags: word, knowledge, cryptic-clues

Your goal is to make sense of these nonsensical phrases:

```
Honored friends.
Officer, tailless corpse.
Zero head life. 
Backwards arrival time
```

and relate the result to the title of this question.

Hint 1:

> The US state I mentioned (namely, Pennsylvania) *is very important*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is obliquely cluing

> several obscure words and phrases on [Wikipedia's list of cryptic crossword abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossword_abbreviations).

Specifically:

> "Honored friends" refers to the Order of the Companions of Honour, giving `CH`.
>  "Officer, tailless corpse." refers to Officer Corps, giving `OC`.
>  "Zero head life" gives `O` and `L_`, the head of "life".
>  "Backwards arrival time" gives `ATE`, from "ETA" backwards.

Together,

> these give the word CHOCOLATE. The "town in Pennsylvania" might be referring to [Hershey, PA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hershey,_Pennsylvania), an unincorporated community that calls itself "the sweetest place on earth".

Comment: Exactly! Upvoted & green-checkmark-ified.

Comment: And of course Hershey's `49@4@=2E6 32CD` (rot47)